# why lualatex gives erorr "Too many open files" but pdflatex does not on same latex file?

Tags: errors, luatex, memory

Using TL 2015 on Linux.

I have a latex file which includes graphics, all in pdf format. All the images are included using the call

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{rules/file_name}
```

There is a total of 1860 such images, all in pdf format.

When I compile this file using lualatex, at some stage, when it gets to image number 1016, it fails with the error `Too many open files`.  Compiling the same file with pdflatex gives no error !

Is there a limitation on how images one can include in a latex file when using lualatex or is this a bug? It looks like lualatex includegraphics version is not closing file handles when loading images and running out of file handles. This is on Linux mint 7.2.

Since the file is large. I have put the file and the images it loads using `\includegraphics` in one zip file (80 MB). The link is at the bottom of this post.

To reproduce, please download the zip file, unzip it using the command `unzip file.zip` and it will create a new folder called `lualatex_error/` and inside this folder there is the one file `report.tex` and the folder that includes all the images. Then typing

```
lualatex report.tex
```

will give the error

```
 lualatex: ./rules/1016.pdf: Too many open files
```

From the `report.log`

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
    (format=lualatex 2015.7.9)  31 JUL 2015 12:28
 restricted \write18 enabled.

lualatex_error>which lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex
```

The zip file is in [this folder](http://12000.org/tmp/073015/) (This is a link to the folder where the zip file is in. Not a direct link to the zip file). 80 MB size.

Any other information I can give please let me know.

Comment: A problem: "You don't have permission to access the requested resource. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance."

Comment: 190,000 lines of `lualatex` code are too dangerous!

Comment: @PaulGaborit See my (non)-answer for a way to reproduce the error without that.

Comment: @Herbert You don't need the OP's code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Can somebody test this on a different OS? I'm also on 64 bit Linux. I also have TL 2015's upstream binaries. (Not using Mint, though ;).)

Comment: To work around this bug, you may try the following command: `unlimit descriptors` (before the compilation).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Linux mint 7.2 does not have this command: `>unlimit descriptors

unlimit: command not found` but I thought file handlers limits is fixed in the system to something like 1024 if I remember and can't be changed by the program. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Nasser The `limit` command is often provided by your shell. `zsh` provides also an `unlimit` command.

Comment: @PaulGaborit No `unlimit` on my system either.

Comment: @Nasser I thought the same thing. I definitely can't find the command here.

Comment: @Nasser Try `ulimit -n`. (Ulrike's suggestion in chat.)

Comment: @Nasser You need to set a new limit e.g. `ulimit -n 2000`. This assumes you are using `bash`. If you use a different shell, the syntax might vary as `ulimit -n` is not in the POSIX spec.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can confirm this behaviour. To test:

Create 1860 copies of `example-image-1x1.pdf` (or other image of your choosing) named `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`,..., `1860.pdf`. If you use `bash` and you have TeX Live 2015 installed in the standard place, you can use the following commands:

```
i=0; while [ $i -le 1860 ] ; do ((i++)); cp /usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-1x1.pdf ./$i.pdf; done
```

Then create the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_nasser_loop_int
\tl_new:N \l_nasser_file_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \icing { }
{
  \int_set:Nn \l_nasser_loop_int { 0 }
  \int_do_while:nNnn { \l_nasser_loop_int } < { 1860 }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_nasser_loop_int
    \tl_set:Nn \l_nasser_file_tl { \int_use:N \l_nasser_loop_int }
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{\l_nasser_file_tl}\par
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\icing
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine with `pdflatex`. With `lualatex`, it fails with the following error:

```
lualatex: ./1024.pdf: Too many open files
```

I will refrain from posting the output `pdflatex` produces: you will either have to take my word for it or follow the procedure above.

Comment: LuaTeX, beta-0.80, rev 5238: Port x86_64-cygwin of TL 2015 breaks at image 3196.pdf, whereas the MiKTeX port (32 bit) runs fine with 10000 images.

Comment: At each page during output, `luatex` opens all external PDF pictures of the page but close only the last opened picture...

Comment: To test with a small number of pictures, you can use the following command: `limit descriptors 20`

Comment: On windows it works without problems. I tested with 5000 pictures on miktex (32bit, LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9) (rev 5238))  and texlive 2015 (LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (rev 5238)).

Comment: @PaulGaborit No `limit` on my system as far as I can tell.

Comment: @cfr With `bash`, try `ulimit -n 20`

Comment: Try `\immediate\includegraphics`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder  I just did. But it did not work I am afraid. On Linux mint 7.2. I still get the same exact error as before.

Comment: for info on mac os x 10.9.5 (bash), the default for `ulimit -n` is only at `256`.  (and lualatex 0.80.0 rev 5238 stops at image 252.pdf). After a first use of `ulimit -n XXX` it is impossible to use it to increase again, one can only use it to decrease the first set value. Using `\immediate` changes nothing to the issue.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Oh, right. Yes, of course. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: @jfbu Yes, but the behaviour itself is obnoxious, is it not? (Or has this been fixed now?)

Comment: @cfr if your last question refers to luatex, I am not adventurous enough to checkout the latest binaries... still with my good old TL2015 ! as per Mac OS, I found this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persist-ulimit-settings-in-osx-mavericks, from which I learn that there is an a priori upper limite at 10240 which can not be exceeded by `ulimit -n` ... except if one follows the procedure described there and reboot ! Anyway, with a default at `256` file handles, mac os x users will quickly encounter the lualatex limitation (if it still exists!)